# Is there any kind of "flow" that describe balloon-like expansion for 2d surfaces constructed via a 1d paths?

Tags: differential-geometry, ricci-flow, mean-curvature-flows

I've looked into Ricci Flow and mean curvature flow/curve shortening flow, but I dont think any of these describe the math behind balloon-like expansion (or even simple diffusion) well enough given that both balloon expansion and diffusion do not go against the natural outward gradient.

Any advice on this?

Comment: What exactly is a balloon-like expansion?

Comment: @ArcticChar Well imagine some closed 1d path and imagine that the "pressure" inside the path (like if the path were some rubber) increased. Then the 1d path would expand. This could also be thought of as simple diffusion which is why i menteiond both

Comment: Well, its a math site. Do you have a more mathematical description of the process?

Comment: I think you want mean curvature flow, modified by adding a constant outward motion. If your 'expanding balloon' is a rubber band around a 2D mass of air, then it will initially have some inward motion while it deforms to a circular shape.

Comment: @1Rock Thanks for your response! How would I determine the rate of the constant outward normal motion and ensure accuracy? Too little, and self-intersections/separations in non-convex polygons will occur; Too much, and the effect of the flow would be negligible. Would it be some sort of tensor relationship? And as a side question q, do you know if other kinds of flow (ricci, yamabe, calabi, inverse mean curvature, etc)?

Comment: I think you get constant-area motion if you add on outward expansion of $\frac{2\pi}{L}$ on a simple closed 2D curve, so you could get expansion by adding anything more than that. You can calculate the rate of area increase, and adjust that to represent the amount of "air" in your balloon. I suspect that self-intersections are physically reasonable under balloon-like expansion.

Comment: @1Rock but what about for complex, and non-convex shapes?

Comment: Over time, the rubber band would pull itself into a circular shape. If you add air at a constant rate, it will expand while it changed its shape, and if you added air fast enough, it would never contract at any point (unless it started with corners).

Comment: @1Rock Yes, but is there a method/formula that defines this more specifically? I would imagine it would be at least similar to possibly area-increasing curve shortening flow, but this is just speculation. Thoughts?